# How can I send an variable into Mail method

Tags: php, laravel

I can send a message correctly , but I have a problem with variable subject , how I can I send the variable $subject into Mail method.

```
->subject($subject)
```

I recieve an undefined variable , this is my code.

```
public function enviarmensaje()
    {
            $email = Request::input('email');
            $subject= Request::input('subject');
            $name = Request::input('nombre');
            $message = Request::input('message');
            $data = array( 'name' => $name , 'correo' => $email , 'mensaje' => $message,'subject'=> $subject );
            Mail::send('contact', $data , function ($message) { 
                $message->to('email@gmail.com','To anyone')->subject("Contact form");
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `use` the `$subject` variable:

```
Mail::send('contact', $data , function ($message) use ($subject) { 
    $message->to('email@gmail.com', 'To anyone')->subject($subject);
});
```

Alternatively, you can call `Request::input('subject')` from within the closure itself:

```
Mail::send('contact', $data , function ($message) { 
    $message->to('email@gmail.com', 'To anyone');

    $message->subject(Request::input('subject'));
});
```